# nvidia GT630M with HDMI second monitor

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, settings, hdmi, asus

I am unable to use double screen with HDMI (works with VGA however) on my ASUS laptop with nvidia 630M

I tried downloading the newest nvidia driver, however I cannot make it work properly and my second screen remains unoticed and black.

This is the message I get with nvidia X Server Settings :

"
You do not appear to be using the NVIDIA X driver.  Please edit your X configuration file (just run `nvidia-xconfig` as root), and restart the X server.
"

My two questions : 
1/ how do I "run" nvidia-xconfig (what is the command line ?) as root (is it "sudo nvidia-xconfig" ?
2/ shall this will make my hdmi port work (it works under W7) or do I have to install something else in ubuntu to make HDMI work ?

Help much appreciated since I want to completely quit MacOS (keeping W7 sadly due to gaming). I found many proposals on forum but only succeeded in 740x480 blocked res as others in this forum have reported.

Regards,
Yohan

Comment: The OP hasn't signed on in 5+ years and appears to have lost interest. Additionally this unanswered question is about EOL Ubuntu version. VTC as `not reproducible`